# Call rabbitmq from nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

i have a code

[image]

i'm get an error when i try to connect to rabbitmq daemon from nodejs

[image]

when i run same code beyond docker then nodejs successfully connect to the server(rabbitmq deamon).

How can i connect from nodejs deamon to rabbitmq deamon?

docker-compose config: 
[image: docker-compose-dev.yml]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the thing: If both node app and the rabbitmq run on separate docker containers, they rely on docker networking to reach each other, so node app looks for a rabbitmq instance **in the same container**, which isn't the case.

RabbitMQ contanier has the port 5672 exposed with a link, which can be reached over the name of the container (according to the standards of docker compose), which means all the exposed ports of that container are available at rabbitmq:. If you change

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost:5672');
```

into

```
amqp.connect('amqp://rabbitmq:5672');
```

You're all good.